# Get the array with the largest object inside an array of an array

Tags: ios, arrays, swift, cllocation

I have an array of an array of CLLocations and I am trying to find the array which has the CLLocation object that happened most recently according to its timestamp. Either the index or the actual list would be sufficient.

So far I have come up with:

```
let latestList = listOfListOfLocations.index{$0.max{a,b in a.timestamp < b.timestamp} < $1.max{c,d in c.timestamp < d.timestamp}}
```

but I'm getting no luck and can't get my head round it being relatively new to Swift. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First get the "submaxes" of each array, and then take the max of those to obtain the global maximum.

```
let subArrayContainingMostRecentObject = listOfListOfLocations
    .flatMap{ subarray in
        return subarray
            .max{ $0.timestamp < $1.timestamp }
            .map{ submax in (subarray: subarray, submax: submax) }
    }
    .max{ $0.submax.timestamp < $1.submax.timestamp }?.subarray
```

Comment: That's great thanks, how could I also change this to get the index?

Comment: @user3599895 Which index?

Comment: Of the array with the most recent timestamp

Comment: Pass it along as one of the members in the tuple (the one that's currently `(subarray: subarray, submax: submax)`)

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if this is the most sufficient implementation, but it works.

`let mostRecent = listOfListOfLocations.max{$0.max{$0.timestamp < $1.timestamp}! < $1.max{$0.timestamp < $1.timestamp}!}?.max()`

Comment: You're better off doing one pass through each sub array to get their maxes, and then one pass through the array of submaxes to get the global max. Otherwise this way, anytime two arrays are compared, the submax of each subarray has to be recomputed